# Weird behavior for Enumerable.Range(starts, count)

Tags: c#, .net, range, enumerable

Look at my code. Why does the Enumerable.Range() behave differently whether the start value is 0.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var range1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 7);
        PrintRange(range1);
        var range2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 8);
        PrintRange(range2);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static void PrintRange(IEnumerable<int> myRange)
    {
        foreach (int i in myRange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Linha {0}\n", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n========================================\n");
    }
}
```

The range itself is the same. however when it starts at 1, I get a larger one. :(
Here is the result:

Linha 0

Linha 1

Linha 2

Linha 3

Linha 4

Linha 5

Linha 6

========================================

Linha 1

Linha 2

Linha 3

Linha 4

Linha 5

Linha 6

Linha 7

Linha 8

========================================

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second argument is `count` not `end`.

Your first call is equivalent to *I want 7 consecutive integers starting with 0* while the second is *I want 8 consectutive integers starting with 1.*

[MSDN Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

Second parameter (`count`) means: how many values to genereate. It is not like start and end values, but start number and number of values, so:

```
// generate 7 integers starting from 0
Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
// generate 8 integers starting from 1
Enumerable.Range(1, 8)
```